# Specflow plugin : Generation error: Missing [assembly:GeneratorPlugin] attribute in

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, specflow, xunit

I am writing a custom plugin to customise the auto-generated code files SpecFlow produces.

After building the solution and putting it in the 'lib' folder of the SpecFlow testing project. On saving the SpecFlow feature file I get

```
Specflow plugin : Generation error: Missing [assembly:GeneratorPlugin] attribute in 'path to dll'
```

Even though I have this marked up in the plugin Assembly

```
[assembly: GeneratorPluginAttribute(typeof(CustomGeneratorPlugin))]
```

Using reflection/self-testing I can load the assembly myself and resolve the attribute

Code is here -- https://github.com/chrismckelt/SpecFlowCustomPlugin

Any ideas whats causing this?  Thanks

Comment: Assembly versioning maybe? Are you sure that the Type of the attribute has a reference to exactly the same assembly as the one that is being defined at runtime by SpecFlow's plugin host?

Comment: And if you are really stuck, you could compile your own copy of specflow from https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow and add a Debugger.Launch() just before it logs the error? Or just use a devenv to debug the devenv you are loading your plugin into?

Comment: Hi yep did the Debugger.Launch - however few problems as its run through VS extensions - changing the VS SpecFlow dlls caused all sort problems (are they signed?) & had to uninstall/reinstall in VS

Comment: Thought about the Version too. Recompile using the same version in the VS SpecFlow Extensions 1.9.2.1 but no luck.   Would be happy to give it another try debugging through Visual Studio Extensions if anyone know if this works?

Comment: You might want to try contacting Gaspar Nagy for advice on getting it to run under debug then (http://stackoverflow.com/users/26530/gaspar-nagy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved by adding the below 'path' attribute to the generator SpecFlow config section

```
<generator path=".\lib"
```

full config

```
<specFlow>
    <generator allowDebugGeneratedFiles="false" allowRowTests="true" generateAsyncTests="false" path=".\lib" />
    <runtime stopAtFirstError="false" missingOrPendingStepsOutcome="Ignore" />
    <trace traceSuccessfulSteps="true" traceTimings="false" minTracedDuration="0:0:0.1" stepDefinitionSkeletonStyle="RegexAttribute" />
    <plugins>
        <add name="McKeltCustom" path=".\lib" type="GeneratorAndRuntime" />
    </plugins>
    <stepAssemblies>
        <stepAssembly assembly="SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic" />
    </stepAssemblies>
</specFlow>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by setting the copy-local flag of all referenced TechTalk.SpecFlow dlls to false in my SpecflowPlugin project.